# Distribution of ratio between two independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability, derived-distributions

Supppse $X$ and $Y$ are standard uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$, and they are independent, what is the PDF of $Z = Y / X$?

The answer from some probability theory textbook is

$$
f_Z(z) = 
\begin{cases}
1/2, & \text{if } 0 \le z \le 1 \\
1/(2z^2), & \text{if } z > 1 \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

I am wondering, by symmetry, shouldn't $f_Z(1/2) = f_Z(2)$? This is not the case according to the PDF above.

Comment: What is the domain of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

Comment: @Sobi $f_X(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @qed: Could you edit the question to include that info? What exactly is your argument from symmetry applied to *densities*?

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true?  The density function tells you how tightly packed the probability is in the neighborhood of a point, and it is clearly more difficult for $Z$ to be near $2$ than $1/2$ (consider for instance that $Z$ can always be $1/2$ no matter what $X$ is, but $Z < 2$ when $X > 1/2$).

Comment: And you can derive the density yourself looking at the unit square and the two different possibilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribution of a ratio of uniforms: What is wrong?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15522/distribution-of-a-ratio-of-uniforms-what-is-wrong)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, that question is seeking the PDF, here I have the PDF, I am just questioning its correctness (perhaps rather naively).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The right logic is that with independent $X, Y \sim U(0,1)$, 
$Z=\frac YX$ and
$Z^{-1} =\frac XY$ have the same *distribution* and so for $0 < z < 1$
\begin{align}
P\left\{\frac YX \leq z\right\} &= P\left\{\frac XY \leq z\right\}\\
&= P\left\{\frac YX \geq \frac 1z \right\}\\
\left.\left.F_{Z}\right(z\right) &= 1 - F_{Z}\left(\frac 1z\right)
\end{align}
where the equation with CDFs uses the fact that $\frac YX$ is a
continuous random variable and so $P\{Z \geq a\} = P\{Z > a\}
= 1-F_Z(a)$. Hence the pdf of $Z$ satisfies
$$f_Z(z) = z^{-2}f_Z(z^{-1}), \quad 0 < z < 1.$$
Thus $f_Z(\frac 12) = 4f_Z(2)$, and not $f_Z(\frac 12) = f_Z(2)$
as you thought it should be.

Answer (score 19):

**This distribution *is* symmetric--if you look at it the right way.**

The symmetry you have (correctly) observed is that $Y/X$ and $X/Y = 1/(Y/X)$ must be identically distributed.  When working with ratios and powers, you are really working within the *multiplicative group* of the positive real numbers.  The analog of the location invariant measure $d\lambda=dx$ on the *additive* real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is the *scale invariant measure* $d\mu = dx/x$ on the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ of positive real numbers.  It has these desirable properties:

1. $d\mu$ is invariant under the transformation $x\to ax$ for any positive constant $a$: $$d\mu(ax) = \frac{d(ax)}{ax} = \frac{dx}{x} = d\mu.$$
2. $d\mu$ is covariant under the transformation $x\to x^b$ for nonzero numbers $b$: $$d\mu(x^b) = \frac{d(x^b)}{x^b} = \frac{b x^{b-1} dx}{x^b} = b\frac{dx}{x} = b\, d\mu.$$
3. $d\mu$ is transformed into $d\lambda$ via the exponential: $$d\mu(e^x) = \frac{de^x}{e^x} = \frac{e^x dx}{e^x} = dx = d\lambda.$$  Likewise, $d\lambda$ is transformed back to $d\mu$ via the logarithm.

(3) establishes an isomorphism between the measured groups $(\mathbb{R}, +, d\lambda)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{*}, *, d\mu)$.  The reflection $x \to -x$ on the additive space corresponds to the inversion $x \to 1/x$ on the multiplicative space, because $e^{-x} = 1/e^x$.

Let's apply these observations by writing the probability element of $Z=Y/X$ in terms of $d\mu$ (understanding implicitly that $z \gt 0$) rather than $d\lambda$:

$$f_Z(z)\,dz = g_Z(z)\,d\mu = \frac{1}{2}\begin{cases}
1\,dz = z\, d\mu, & \text{if } 0 \le z \le 1 \\
\frac{1}{z^2}dz = \frac{1}{z}\, d\mu, & \text{if } z > 1. 
\end{cases}$$

That is, the PDF *with respect to the invariant measure $d\mu$* is $g_Z(z)$, proportional to $z$ when $0\lt z \le 1$ and to $1/z$ when $1 \le z$, close to what you had hoped.

---

This is not a mere one-off trick.  Understanding the role of $d\mu$ makes many formulas look simpler and more natural.  For instance, the probability element of the Gamma function with parameter $k$, $x^{k-1}e^x\,dx$ becomes $x^k e^x d\mu$.  It's easier to work with $d\mu$ than with $d\lambda$ when transforming $x$ by rescaling, taking powers, or exponentiating.

The idea of an [invariant measure on a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) is far more general, too, and has [applications in that area of statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Mathematical_statistics) where problems exhibit some invariance under groups of transformations (such as changes of units of measure, rotations in higher dimensions, and so on).

Comment: Looks like a very insightful answer. It's a pity I don't understand it at the moment. I will check back later.

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1:** Let $X_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $X_2\sim U(0,1)$. Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, $$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1).f_{X_2}(x_2)=1.$$

Define $Y_1=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ and $Y_2=X_2$. It means that $Y_1=u_1(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y_2=u_2(X_1,X_2)$ where $u_1(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and $u_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$. Now, let's find $X_1,X_2$ in terms of $Y_1,Y_2$. We get:
$$X_1=Y_1Y_2 \mbox{ and } X_2=Y_2.$$
In other words, $X_1=v_1(Y_1,Y_2)$ and  $X_2=v_2(Y_2)$ where $v_1(y_1,y_2)=y_1y_2$ and $v_2(y_1,y_2)=y_2$.

Calculate the Jacobian and we have 
$$J= \det\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y_2} \\ \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y_2} \end{matrix}\right] =\det\left[\begin{matrix}y_2 & y_1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]=y_2. $$
So we have 
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=f_{X_1,X_2}(v_1(y_1,y_1),v_2(y_1,y_2)).|J| = y_2.$$

Now, we can calculate the marginal pdf of $Y_1$. Note that the region 
$$\{(x_1,x_2)|0<x_1<1,0<x_2<1\}$$
maps to the region 
$$\{(y_1,y_2)|y_1>0,y_2<\min\{1,1/y_1\}\}.$$

[image]

So we have:

$$f_{Y_1}(y_1)=\int f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)dy_2=\left\{\begin{matrix} \int_{0}^{1}y_2dy_2 & 0<y_1<1\\ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{y_1}}y_2dy_2 & y_1>1\end{matrix}\right. = \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0<y_1<1 \\ \frac{1}{2y_1^2} &  y_1>1.\end{matrix}\right.$$

**Method 2:** Let $X_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $X_2\sim U(0,1)$. Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, $$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1).f_{X_2}(x_2)=1.$$ Let $Z=\frac{X_2}{X_1}$. We have

$$F(z)=P(Z\le z) = P(\frac{X_2}{X_1} \le z) = P(X_2\le zX_1).$$

Note that if $0<z<1$, then the slope of the line $X_2=zX_1$ is less than 1 and this line is in region 1 (below the line $X_2=X_1$), otherwise it will be in region 2 (above the line $X_2=X_1$) (See the picture).

[image]

So we have
$$ F(z)= P(X_2\le zX_1)=\left\{ \begin{matrix} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{zx_1} 1dx_2dx_1 & 0<z<1 \\ \int_{0}^{1/z}\int_{0}^{zx_1} 1dx_2dx_1+\int_{1/z}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} 1dx_2dx_1 & z>1 \end{matrix}\right.$$
$$ =\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2}z & 0<z<1 \\ 1-\frac{1}{2z} & z>1 \end{matrix}\right.$$

So, the pdf is

$$ f(z)=\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0<z<1 \\ \frac{1}{2z^2} & z>1 \end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: I appreciate detailed answers like this. Very helpful.

Comment: Method 2 helped me beyond measure. Finding the limits of integration did not make sense until you showed the multiple discontinuities at z=1 and x=1/z.

Comment: draw a picture!! +1

Answer (score 9):

If you think geometrically...

In the $X$-$Y$ plane, curves of constant $Z = Y/X$ are lines through the origin.  ($Y/X$ is the slope.)  One can read off the value of $Z$ from a line through the origin by finding its intersection with the line $X=1$.  (If you've ever studied projective space: here $X$ is the homogenizing variable, so looking at values on the slice $X=1$ is a relatively natural thing to do.)

Consider a small interval of $Z$s, $(a,b)$.  This interval can also be discussed on the line $X=1$ as the line segment from $(1,a)$ to $(1,b)$.  The set of lines through the origin passing through this interval forms a solid triangle in the square $(X,Y) \in U = [0,1]\times[0,1]$, which is the region we're actually interested in.  If $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$, then the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}(1-0)(b-a)$, so keeping the length of the interval constant and sliding it up and down the line $X=1$ (but not past $0$ or $1$), the area is the same, so the probability of picking an $(X,Y)$ in the triangle is constant, so the probability of picking a $Z$ in the interval is constant.

However, for $b>1$, the boundary of the region $U$ turns away from the line $X = 1$ and the triangle is truncated.  If $1 \leq a < b$, the projections down lines through the origin from $(1,a)$ and $(1,b)$ to the upper boundary of $U$ are to the points $(1/a,1)$ and $(1/b,1)$.  The resulting area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b})(1-0)$.  From this we see the area is not uniform and as we slide $(a,b)$ further and further to the right, the probability of selecting a point in the triangle decreases to zero.

Then the same algebra demonstrated in other answers finishes the problem.  In particular, returning to the OP's last question, $f_Z(1/2)$ corresponds to a line that reaches $X=1$, but $f_Z(2)$ does not, so the desired symmetry does not hold.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, my intuition was totally wrong. We are talking about **density**, not **probability**. The right logic is to check that

$$
\int_1^k f_Z(z) dz = \int_{1/k}^1 f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{1}{k})
$$,

and this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yea the link [Distribution of a ratio of uniforms: What is wrong?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15522/distribution-of-a-ratio-of-uniforms-what-is-wrong) provides CDF of $Z=Y/X$. 
The PDF here is just derivative of the CDF. So the formula is correct. I think your problem lies in the assumption that you think Z is "symmetric" around 1. However this is not true. Intuitively Z should be a skewed distribution, for example it is useful to think when Y is a fixed number between $(0,1)$ and X is a number close to 0, thus the ratio would be going to infinity. So the symmetry of distribution is not true. I hope this help a bit.