# Are the beta distribution and binomial distribution related?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

I've seen questions like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/relationship-between-binomial-and-beta-distributions) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277643/whence-the-beta-distribution), but it hasn't quite answered my question. How intertwined are the Beta and Binomial distributions?

A quick sidenote: the Poisson distribution and the exponential distribution are two faces of the same coin. The Poisson distributions is a count process for events whereas the exponential distribution models time between those *same* events.

I know the Beta distribution is a convenient way to model the uncertainty in $p$ in a Binomial distribution because the Beta distribution is flexible (with the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters) and exists between 0 and 1 (just like probabilities should be). But is there more to the story? Are the Beta distribution and Binomial distribution two faces of the same coin as well?

Comment: Have you searched our site yet?  Try [beta binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta+binomial). A nice trick is to focus on the upvoted posts: [beta binomial score:2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta+binomial+score%3A2) narrows the field a bit and [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta+binomial+-%22beta-binomial%22+score%3A2) excludes the closely associated "beta-binomial" distribution.  There's still a large amount of information already posted about this. An explicit account appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659.