# Symmetric distribution with finite Mean but no Variance

Tags: distributions, example

Is there a *symmetric* continuous distribution that has a finite mean, but no variance?

What I've found so far: For instance the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) satisfies everything but the symmetry, so I was wondering, can we also construct a *symmetric* distribution?

It is easy to see that if the mean exists for a symmetric distribution, it must be zero. So if the variance $\sigma^2$ did not exist, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 f(x) dx= 2\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)$ would have to diverge. But I did not manage to construct such an $f$ with a finite mean.

Comment: You can make any distribution that satisfies your criteria symmetric by independently sampling from it or its negation with probability 1/2 each.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That is a nice construction, thanks! Is it clear though that these properties still hold in this construction (mean exists, variance does not)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $t$ distribution with two degrees of freedom satisfies your criteria. A $t$ distribution has a mean of zero when the degrees of freedom are greater than $1$ (otherwise undefined) but has no variance until the degrees of freedom exceeds $2$.

All $t$ distributions are continuous and symmetric.

I disagree that the mean of such a distribution has to be zero, however, to satisfy your criteria. A shifted $t$ distribution satisfies your criteria but can be centered anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding the mean having to be zero: If the PDF is symmetric in the sense that $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$, then the mean should be zero: $\begin{align*} \\ \mu &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx  \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^0 x f(x)dx + \int_0^\infty x f(x)dx 
\\&= -\int_{\infty}^0 (-x)f(-x)dx + \int_0^\infty x f(x)dx \\&= -\int_0^\infty x f(-x)dx + \int_0^\infty x f(x)dx 
\\&= -\int_0^\infty x f(x)dx + \int_0^\infty x f(x)dx = 0.
\end{align*}$

Comment: Yes - note that symmetry becomes irrelevant when you put an $x^2$ in the integrand, or consider $|f|$ instead of $f$.

Comment: Yes, it depends on your definition of symmetric. You mean that the PDF is an even function. My definition relaxes the assumptions and just means symmetry about the mean. I would expect most statisticians to use my definition (that’s why I use it), but if your field or your class uses your definition, go for it.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for clarifying, I just used the *function*-notion of symmetry, I wasn't aware of the one used in stats, but I guess the idea is the same.

Comment: I know it's a little bit nitpicky, but maybe *symmetry around the mean* is not the best way to describe it, if you e.g. consider a shifted Cauchy distribution:)

Comment: The statistical definition of symmetrical distribution is the same as the mathematical one: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29010/919 and (for an even more general definition) https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185709/919. In particular, it does not require a mean to exist. The definition employed in the comments is overly limited in that it requires the distribution to have a density with finite absolute first moment.  Without that latter assumption, the manipulations in the first comment are incorrect, because they assert that $-\infty+\infty=0.$

Answer (score 4):

The [symmetric α-stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) with $\alpha \in (1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this class of distributions!