# find pdf (using bivariate transformation) of X/Y where X,Y ~ uniform(0,1) independent

Tags: self-study, distributions

I know how to find the distribution of X/Y when they are independent uniform(0,1) by drawing the integration area.

Correct answer is:

$$
P(X/Y \leqslant t) = \\  \frac{1}{2} t, t\leqslant1\\1-\frac{1}{2t},t>1
$$

But when I use bivariate transformation $U=\frac{X}{Y}$ and $V=Y$ I find the following problem.

$$
f_{U,V}(u,v) = v \text{ where }0\leqslant v \leqslant 1, 0\leqslant u \leqslant \frac{1}{v}
$$

$$
f_U(u) = \int_{0}^{1} f_{U,V}(u,v)dv=\int_{0}^{1} vdv=\frac{1}{2}
$$

which is the pdf when $t\leqslant1$. How to get the other part?

Thanks!

Comment: A google search gives the links https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15522/119261, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113295/321264. Regarding your method, there is dependency between $u$ and $v$ which has to be taken into account in the integration for finding the marginal densities.

Comment: Inverting $$u\le 1/v$$ leads to $$v\le \min\{1,1/u\}$$