# Ratio of Two Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, continuous-data, uniform-distribution, bivariate

If X1 X2 are independent Uniform variates on (0,1), Find the distribution of Z=X1/X2.

I tried using the CDF method where P(X1<=zX2) is equal to z/2 when z is in(0,1). However, I am unable to find the CDF when z is greater than 1

Comment: $P(X_1\leq z X_2)=1/2$ is not correct $\forall z\in (0,1)$

Comment: Sorry, it’s z/2

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15522/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185683/119261

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P( Z \leq z ) &= \mathbb P(X_1 \leq zX_2) \\
&= \int_0^1  \mathbb P( X_1 \leq zx_2) dx_2
\end{align*}

When $z \leq 1$ then  $\forall x_2 \in (0,1)$, $ \mathbb P( X_1 \leq zx_2)= zx_2$ and $\mathbb P( Z \leq z ) = \frac{z}{2}$.

When $z\geq 1$ you have to split the integral into two parts: a first one where $zx_2 \leq 1$ for all $x_2$ and a second one where $zx_2 \geq 1$.
Since $zx_2 \leq 1 \iff x_2 \leq \frac{1}{z}$, we have for $z\geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P( Z \leq z ) &=\int_0^{z^{-1}}  \mathbb P( X_1 \leq zx_2) dx_2 + \int_{z^{-1}}^1  \mathbb P( X_1 \leq zx_2) dx_2 \\
&=\int_0^{z^{-1}} zx_2 dx_2 + \int_{z^{-1}}^1  dx_2 \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2z}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The support is the unit square. When $z>1$, the line $X_1=zX_2$ crosses the unit square where $x_1=1,x_2=1/z$. The area over the line (intersecting the unit square) is $1-{1\over {2z}}$. This area equals to the probability you ask since the PDF is uniform and equals to $1$.